# Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I have an error I am not sure how to solve it. I tried adding `?? ""` after `$customer->name` did not work.

> lluminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleError
>   C:\laragon\www\zorland-app\resources\views/invoices/create.blade.php:33

create.blade.php

```
<div class="float-left col-md-6">
             Odaberi kupca: <b>{{ $customer->name  }}</b>
            <input type="hidden" name="invoice[customer_id]" value="{{ $customer->id }}" />
</div>
```

Customer.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    //

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'address', 'postcode', 'city', 'state', 'country_id', 'postcode', 'phone', 'email'];

    public function customer_fields() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CustomersField::class);
    }
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class);
    }
}
```

CustomersController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Country;
use App\Customer;
use App\CustomersField;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class CustomersController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $customers = Customer::all();
        return view( 'customers.index', compact('customers'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $countries = Country::all();
        return view('customers.create', compact('countries'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $customer = Customer::create($request->all());
        for ($i=0; $i < count($request->customer_fields); $i++) {
            if (isset($request->customer_fields[$i]['field_key']) && isset($request->customer_fields[$i]['field_value'])) {
                CustomersField::create([
                    'customer_id' => $customer->id,
                    'field_key' => $request->customer_fields[$i]['field_key'],
                    'field_value' => $request->customer_fields[$i]['field_value']

                ]);
            }

        } 
        return redirect()->route('customers.index');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

InvoicesController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Customer;
use App\CustomersField;
use App\Invoice;
use App\InvoicesItem;
use App\Product;

class InvoicesController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function create(Request $request) 
    {
        $customer = Customer::find($request->customer_id);
        $tax = 0;
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('invoices.create', compact('tax', 'products', 'customer'));
    }
    public function store(Request $request) 
    {
        $invoice = Invoice::create($request->invoice);

        for ($i=0; $i < count($request->product); $i++) {
            if (isset($request->qty[$i]) && isset($request->price[$i])) {
                InvoicesItem::create([
                    'invoice_id' => $invoice->id,
                    'name' => $request->product[$i],
                    'quantity' => $request->qty[$i],
                    'price' => $request->price[$i]
                ]);
            }

        } 



        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    public function show($invoice_id) 
    {

        $invoice = Invoice::findOrFail($invoice_id);
        return view('invoices.show', compact( 'invoice')); 
    }

    public function download($invoice_id) 
    {

        $invoice = Invoice::findOrFail($invoice_id);
        $pdf     = \PDF::loadView('invoices.pdf', compact('invoice'));

        return $pdf->stream('invoice.pdf');
    }

}
```

Comment: try this `{{ isset($customer) ? $customer->name : '' }}` and the one you tried need to be in this way, somehow `{{ $customer->name ?? $customer->name }}`

Comment: i have ammended the code, now i have another error: ``` Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`zorland-app`.`invoices`, CONSTRAINT `invoices_customer_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `invoices` (`invoice_number`, `invoice_date`, `tax_percent`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (gsfhsfh, 08-06-2020, 0, 2020-06-08 12:27:45, 2020-06-08 12:27:45)) ```

Comment: You have issue in your database fields for a foreign key, check that accordingly